# 301 Redirect Multiple Directories with new structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I am helping out with a site that has hundreds of blog posts that are in this format:

```
http://somesite.com/everyday-tech/a-blog-post-1
http://somesite.com/everyday-life/a-blog-post-2
```

Every post is currently either under "everyday-tech" or "everyday-life".

The client would like to have all of the posts in this format:

```
http://somesite.com/category-1/a-blog-post-1
http://somesite.com/category-2/a-blog-post-2
```

Edit: The categories will changed based on wordpress post category, which there are dozens of.

I know how to re-write the permalinks in WP for the 2nd format, however I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do 301 redirects here as we need to keep the "link juice".  Or do I have to do each individual post as a redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place these two 301 redirect rules right below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^everyday-tech/(.+)$ /category-1/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^everyday-life/(.+)$ /category-2/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

**EDIT:** If there isn't a direct correlation between everyday-tech/life and a category then in that case no rewrite rule can help you because a rule can only work on matching a known pattern and translate that into a specific target. In your case target is unknown.

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify that category-X could be any of dozens of categories, whatever the wordpress post falls under.

Comment: But you have to map `everyday-tech` to some specific category in WP right? What is that category name?

Comment: No they do not map to specific things. There may be things in both everyday-tech and everyday-life that are now going to point to site.com/category/post-name.  There isn't a direct correlation between everyday-tech/life and a category

Comment: `There isn't a direct correlation between everyday-tech/life and a category ` Well in that case no rewrite rule can help you because a rule can only work on matching a known pattern and translate that into a specific target. In your case target is unknown.

Comment: If you will add the above as an answer I will mark it as answered.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I have edited my answer so that you can accept it whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess file, try adding this *before* any wordpress rules that are there:

```
RewriteRule ^everyday-tech/(.*)$ /category-1/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^everyday-life/(.*)$ /category-2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify that category-X could be any of dozens of categories, whatever the wordpress post falls under.